# How to pass -Xfrozen_modules=off to python to disable frozen modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Running a python script on VS outputs this error. How to pass -Xfrozen_modules=off to python to disable frozen modules?

[image: snippet of the shell]

I was trying to update the python version from 3.6 to 3.11 and then started seeing this message.

Comment: if you are using VS Code try adding `"pythonArgs": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"]` to your debug configuration in launch.json

Comment: @torakaou Post that as an answer.

Comment: I did. Please upvote so I wont be banned again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using VS Code you can add `"pythonArgs": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"]` to your debug configuration in `launch.json`, like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python (Xfrozen=off)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "pythonArgs": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is some additional context in the GitHub Issue [fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/213](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/213).

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Studio 2019

In the example screenshots, the project I was using (i.e. "*YourProjectName*" in the following instructions) was "PythonExperiment".

1. **Project** menu > ***YourProjectName* Properties**

[image: Location of Project menu and Project Properties menu option]

- *Alternative Step 1*: Click the dropdown arrow of the "Start" button in the header and select ***YourProjectName* Debug Properties** from the dropdown menu.

[image]

2. A new tab should open having the name of *YourProjectName*.  Inside the tab, ensure **Debug** is selected on the left.  On the right, look for the **Run** section.  Enter `-Xfrozen_modules=off` into the **Interpreter Arguments** textbox.

[image: Location of Interpreter Arguments within Project Properties - Debug settings]

3. **Save** your changes.  You can close the tab.